# How to solve "Response code:503 Response message:Service Temporarily Unavailable" this error?

Tags: jmeter, performance-testing, load-testing, jmeter-5.0

Thread Name:Thread Group 1-1
Sample Start:2022-04-26 14:22:39 IST
Load time:230
Connect Time:159
Latency:226
Size in bytes:11283
Sent bytes:498
Headers size in bytes:797
Body size in bytes:10486
Sample Count:1
Error Count:1
Data type ("text"|"bin"|""):text
Response code:503
Response message:Service Temporarily Unavailable

HTTPSampleResult fields:
ContentType: text/html; charset=UTF-8
DataEncoding: UTF-8

Answer (score 0):

As per the [error description](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Status/503):

> **503 Service Unavailable**
>
> The HyperText Transfer Protocol (HTTP) `503 Service Unavailable` server error response code indicates that the server is not ready to handle the request.
>
> Common causes are a server that is **down for maintenance or that is overloaded**. This response should be used for temporary conditions and the [`Retry-After`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Headers/Retry-After) HTTP header should, if possible, contain the estimated time for the recovery of the service.

so there is nothing you can "solve" here.

1. If the server is down for the maintenance - you just need to wait until it's back
2. If the server is overloaded - congratulations on finding the [bottleneck](https://www.quora.com/What-is-bottleneck-in-performance-testing), if you want to investigate further you might want to check:

   - your application and middleware configuration, you might need to tune it for the high loads
   - your application resources consumption (CPU, RAM, etc.) as if it lacks resources you might need to migrate to more powerful hardware, it can be done using [JMeter PerfMon plugin](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/how-monitor-your-server-health-performance-during-jmeter-load-test)
   - repeat your test with a [profiler tool](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_performance_analysis_tools) or an [APM tool](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Application_performance_management) telemetry enabled, this way you will be able to tell for sure where the problem is